# Tallying within a variable per participant

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 18 participants and 350 entries per participant. I have a specific variable (talk) that has a code of 1 (yes) or 0 (no). I want to tally how many times it switches from 0 to 1 per participant and add a column with those values. I tried using aggregate across the dataset but I did not want the mean, simply the n amount of times it switches.

DATA SAMPLE:

```
    VP code
    1a      0
    1a      1
    1a      0
    1a      1
    ...
    1b      0
    1b      1
    1b      0
    1b      1
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
    VP switch
    1a      2
    1b      2
    2a      2
    2b      2
    ...
```

Essentially, I have 2 participants interacting, and I want to see count the amount of turns they take (ie. times they switch talking).

Any advice? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be collapsing with `toString` and then using `str_count` from `stringr`:

```
transform(
  aggregate(code ~ VP, FUN = toString, data = df),
  code = stringr::str_count(code, '0, 1')
)
```

Output:

```
  VP code
1 1a    2
2 1b    2
```